# Text Input not allowing text to be entered on Safari though the cursor changes as though it can click into the box

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a text input box for quantity of products on this page that is in development. On Safari, it is not allowing text to be entered though the cursor changes as though it can click into the box. The box functions normally on other browsers such as Safari.

Web Page: http://test.wearecape.com/bagtags/product/4-x-5-event-pass/

After Looking at past problems that were similar, I tried adding the following:

```css
.touxt_single_product .touxt-add-to-cart .quantity input.qty{
 -webkit-user-select: text;
  -khtml-user-select: text;
  -moz-user-select: text;
  -ms-user-select: text;
  user-select: text;
}
```

However, that did not seem to work. Any ideas? I'm at a loss on this one as I don't frequently work with inputs. Also, the site is built on a wordpress and woo commerce template, so the code is a little untidy.

Comment: What type of input is your quantity field?

Comment: Its a text input

`code`
<input id="ova_touxt_69984505" step="1" min="1" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4" type="text">